# running R in C#

Tags: c#, .net, r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call R (programming language) from .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025340/call-r-programming-language-from-net)

Is there a way to run R from within C# code without installing the R itself? I'm trying to use R.NET now, and it seems that it needs to have R installed. What I want is something that I can just reference the R dll into without installing R with any setup. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025340/call-r-programming-language-from-net

Answer (score 3):

R.NET does not just replace R. It acts as an interface between your C# code and R (i.e. still need R locally). Have you had a look at [Rapache](http://rapache.net/)?

Answer (score 1):

To do this in C# you'll need to use
shell (R CMD BATCH myRprogram.R)

Be sure to wrap your plots like such
pdf(file="myoutput.pdf")
plot (x,y)
dev.off()
or image wrappers.