# Accessing R library from Visual Studio using C#

Tags: c#, .net, r

I'd like to develop a C# program for some statistical calculations by accessing the R-Library under .NET using Visual Studio. There is an interface called R.NET but it is buggy and no longer maintained. Is here an open source interface to R Library under .NET?

Comment: Why do you feel that R.NET is buggy? I use it on a regular basis and have never encountered any problems. The only thing which seems to be tricky is to get plotting right.

Comment: I was referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025340/call-r-programming-language-from-net.

Comment: That answer is from 2012. The latest nuget release from R.NET (https://www.nuget.org/packages/R.NET.Community/) is from 2015. I guess they did multiple improvements in 3 years.